# How to update Drupal Views 2 query with OR expression?

Tags: drupal, view, alter

I'd like to add an OR expression to Drupal 6.x Views 2 query in the following way:

Existing query:

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid FROM node node WHERE (expr1) AND (expr2)
```

New query - this is what I want to achieve:

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid FROM node node WHERE (expr1) AND (expr2 OR new_expr)
```

The question is how to update my existing query (build with Views 2 UI) with views_query_alter or some other hook in order to get `expr2` **OR**'ed with `new_expr`?

Comment: did either of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Views Or](http://drupal.org/project/views_or) - dev version, but it's work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Views Version 3.0 (currently in alpha3 so quite stable) http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-6.x-3.0-alpha3.tar.gz

It supports `OR`ing of views filters out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. However, I don't want to migrate to Views 3 yet.

Comment: Try it. Views 3 is quite stable and has tons of new features!